# sprintf argument swapping and HEREDOC

Tags: php, printf, heredoc, nowdoc

I'm trying to use sprintf on a heredoc this way. It wont work. Any idea how to solve this?

```
$i = <<<EOD
This is your invoice for %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s
EOD;

$year = '2013';

$i = sprintf($i,$year);

echo $i;
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: s in

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because HEREDOC acts like a double-quoted string, PHP is attempting to interpolate the `$s` as a variable. Try [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead

```
$i = <<<'EOD'
This is your invoice for %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s
EOD;
```

Answer (score 4):

Or just escape the dollar signs:

```
$i = <<<EOD
This is your invoice for %1\$s %1\$s %1\$s %1\$s
EOD;
```

This is useful e.g. in PHP 5.2 where there's no nowdoc syntax.